# Error code in a SPI camera connected to raspberry pi - micropython code

Tags: micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I've got the following code:

```
import machine
import time as utime
from OV5642_reg import *

OV5642=1

BMP =0
JPEG=1
RAW =2

OV5642_CHIPID_HIGH=0x300a
OV5642_CHIPID_LOW=0x300b

class ArducamClass(object):
    def __init__(self,Type):
        self.CameraMode=JPEG
        self.CameraType=Type
        self.SPI_CS = machine.Pin(5, mode=machine.Pin.OUT, value=1)
        self.I2cAddress=0x3c
        self.spi = machine.SPI(0, baudrate=4000000,polarity=0,phase=0,bits=8, sck=machine.Pin(2), mosi=machine.Pin(3), miso=machine.Pin(4))
        self.i2c = machine.I2C(0, scl=machine.Pin(9), sda=machine.Pin(8), freq=1000000)
        print(self.i2c.scan())
        self.Spi_write(0x07,0x80)
        utime.sleep(0.1)
        self.Spi_write(0x07,0x00)
        utime.sleep(0.1)

    def Camera_Detection(self):
        while True:
            if self.CameraType==OV5642:
                self.I2cAddress=0x3c
                self.wrSensorReg16_8(0xff,0x01)
                id_h=self.rdSensorReg16_8(OV5642_CHIPID_HIGH)
                id_l=self.rdSensorReg16_8(OV5642_CHIPID_LOW)
                if((id_h==0x56)and(id_l==0x42)):
                    print('CameraType is OV5642')
                    break
                else:
                    print('Can\'t find OV5642 module')
            utime.sleep(1)
            
    def Set_Camera_mode(self,mode):
        self.CameraMode=mode

    def wrSensorReg16_8(self,addr,val):
        buffer=bytearray(3)
        buffer[0]=(addr>>8)&0xff
        buffer[1]=addr&0xff
        buffer[2]=val
        self.iic_write(buffer)    

    def rdSensorReg16_8(self,addr):
        buffer=bytearray(2)
        rt=bytearray(1)
        buffer[0]=(addr>>8)&0xff
        buffer[1]=addr&0xff
        self.iic_write(buffer)
        self.iic_readinto(rt)
        return rt[0]

    def iic_write(self, buf, *, start=0, end=None):
        if end is None:
            end = len(buf)
        self.i2c.writeto(self.I2cAddress, buf[start:end])

    def iic_readinto(self, buf, *, start=0, end=None):
        if end is None:
            end = len(buf)
            print(buf[start:end])
            print(self.I2cAddress)
        self.i2c.readfrom_into(self.I2cAddress, buf[start:end])

    def Spi_write(self,address,value):
        maskbits = 0x80
        buffer=bytearray(2)
        buffer[0]=address | maskbits
        buffer[1]=value
        self.SPI_CS.value(0)
        self.spi_write(buffer)
        self.SPI_CS.value(1)

    def spi_write(self, buf, *, start=0, end=None):
            if end is None:
                end = len(buf)
            self.spi.write(buf[start:end])


mycam = ArducamClass(OV5642)
mycam.Camera_Detection()
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 89, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 33, in Camera_Detection
  File "<stdin>", line 58, in rdSensorReg16_8
  File "<stdin>", line 71, in iic_readinto
OSError: [Errno 5] EIO
```

I'm sure that the camera is connected correctly (I've tested it using the standard CircuitPython code provided with it and it works) so I think that I'm misinterpreting how the readfrom_into call works... any hint?

I tried to understand what get's written in the readfrom_into part but can't get anything.. The starting code (based on circuitpython) is here: https://github.com/ArduCAM/PICO_SPI_CAM/blob/master/Python/Arducam.py